# Near Expiry Event Trigger for Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-eventgrid

I have an event subscription in key vault for near expiry for a Secrect I created.
I have expiry date of the key 60 minutes but I am not sure when would near expire event trigger. Is it 5 minutes before the expiry date time or 10 minutes or 1 minute. Where is it configured and Can I override that?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation [Azure Key Vault as Event Grid source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema), the `Microsoft.KeyVault.KeyNearExpiry` event is described as follows:

> Triggered when the current version of a key is about to expire. The event time can be configured using [key rotation policy(preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/how-to-configure-key-rotation)

and

> The key rotation policy allows users to configure rotation interval, expiration interval for rotated keys, and near expiry notification period for monitoring expiration using event grid notifications.

Comment: There is no option for Secrets unfortunately. that topic covers Keys only.